# No device found on COMx

Tags: arduino

First attempt at arduino, but I have a coding background.

Developing on a Windows 10 PC and I'm using vs code as my IDE with platformio. I believe the Device is an adafruit QT PY based on comparing images. It was given to me by a friend so not 100% sure.

Code I'm trying to upload:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting demo...");
}
// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  Serial.println("Start of Loop");
  delay(1000);
}
```

platformio.ini

```
[env:adafruit_qt_py_m0]
platform = atmelsam
board = adafruit_qt_py_m0
framework = arduino
upload_protocol = sam-ba
```

It builds, but fails to upload for some reason. The LED on the arduino is lit up, but when I click upload it shuts off and I hear the device disconnect sound from my PC. I've disconnected and reconnected the arduino and rebooted my PC.

```
Processing adafruit_qt_py_m0 (platform: atmelsam; board: adafruit_qt_py_m0; framework: arduino)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/atmelsam/adafruit_qt_py_m0.html
PLATFORM: Atmel SAM (8.1.0) > Adafruit QT Py M0
HARDWARE: SAMD21E18A 48MHz, 32KB RAM, 256KB Flash
DEBUG: Current (atmel-ice) External (atmel-ice, blackmagic, jlink)
PACKAGES:
 - framework-arduino-samd-adafruit @ 1.7.10
 - framework-cmsis @ 2.50400.181126 (5.4.0)
 - framework-cmsis-atmel @ 1.2.2
 - tool-bossac @ 1.10700.190624 (1.7.0)
 - toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi @ 1.90301.200702 (9.3.1)
LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/librarymanager/ldf.html
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 11 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
No dependencies
Building in release mode
Checking size .pio\build\adafruit_qt_py_m0\firmware.elf
Advanced Memory Usage is available via "PlatformIO Home > Project Inspect"
RAM:   [=         ]   8.0% (used 2608 bytes from 32768 bytes)
Flash: [          ]   3.9% (used 10208 bytes from 262144 bytes)
Configuring upload protocol...
AVAILABLE: atmel-ice, blackmagic, jlink, sam-ba
CURRENT: upload_protocol = sam-ba
Looking for upload port...
Auto-detected: COM4
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port COM4
Waiting for the new upload port...
Uploading .pio\build\adafruit_qt_py_m0\firmware.bin
No device found on COM4
*** [upload] Error 1
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Are you sure the device is connected in COM4. This port is autodetected but might not be the correct one if you have more than 1 COM port available. Make sure you select the proper COM port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to upload. The board was incorrectly identified. I updated my platformio config as follows:

```
[env:adafruit_qtpy_esp32s3_nopsram]
platform = espressif32
board = adafruit_qtpy_esp32s3_nopsram
framework = arduino
upload_protocol = esptool
```